# FileNotFoundException when create new FileOutputStream

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.setOut(new PrintStream (new FileOutputStream("out.txt", false)));
    while(sc.hasNext()) System.out.println(sc.nextInt());

}
```

I've tried the above code and got this

```
Error:(9, 40) java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community, anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.setOut(new PrintStream (new FileOutputStream("out.txt", false)));
    while(sc.hasNext()) System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
}
```

you need to throw it at the method declaration or you can use try catch block

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream (new FileOutputStream("out.txt", false)));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printstacktrace();
    }
    while(sc.hasNext())
        System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
}
```